# SwiftUI Slider Customize Thumb Image

Tags: swift, swiftui, slider

Is there a way to customize the thumb image on SwiftUI sliders?

I know there is a few ways using UIKit but ideally I want to stay away completely.

I am creating a custom Slider with tick marks like this:

```
        ZStack {
            HStack {
                ForEach(0...10, id: \.self) { _ in
                    Text("I")
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .foregroundColor(ColorStyle(colorAsset: .lightGrey).color)
                }
            }
            Slider(value: $viewModel.sliderValue, in: minSlider...maxSlider, step: sliderStep)
                .tint(ColorStyle(colorAsset: .lightGrey).color)
        }
```

Comment: As Apple adds more customization to swift ui you may be stuck using UIAppearance and the like, as you mentioned. Otherwise you're likely stuck making your own slider from scratch!

Answer (score -3):

IOS14 and up:

you can customize the thumb image on a SwiftUI slider by using the thumbImage modifier.

```
Slider(value: $sliderValue, in: 0...100, step: 1)
    .thumbImage(yourCustomImage)
```

IOS 13 and lower:

To create a custom slider style with a custom thumb image, you will need to create a new struct that conforms to the SliderStyle protocol:

```
struct MySliderStyle: SliderStyle {
    func makeThumb(configuration: Self.ThumbConfiguration) -> some View {
      // Return your custom thumb image here
    }
}
```

To use this custom slider style, you can apply it to a slider using the sliderStyle modifier, like this:

```
Slider(value: $sliderValue, in: 0...100, step: 1)
   .sliderStyle(MySliderStyle())
```

Comment: Value of type 'Slider<EmptyView, EmptyView>' has no member 'thumbImage'

Comment: neither of these options work